# SharePoint - 14/Layouts web config changes programatically

Tags: web-config, spwebconfigmodification, layouts

I want to add web config changes to my 14/LAYOUTS/web.config file.
How can i achieve this.

Comment: What specific changes do you need to do? You can add custom web.config files to subfolders of the LAYOUTS directory and these are merged when application pages in those folders are accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing, a less-invasive option would be to store data in the property bag for the web application, which would avoid the need to modify the web.config.

You can use the [SharePoint Property Bag Settings 2010](http://pbs2010.codeplex.com/) project to add/manage property bag keys, or create them with PowerShell or an Event Receiver.

Answer (score 1):

agree with James. try to put your InputCsvFile.aspx in a subfolder in Layouts, then put web.config file in the same subfolder with your nodes (configuration -> location; etc)